# How do I join the rest of the array after having removed an element in a specific index?

Tags: python, arrays, join, queue

How do I join the rest of the array after having removed an element in a specific index?
I want the "holes" None to disappear.
The constructor:

```
def __init__(self, capacity=8):
    self.__data = [None] * capacity
    self.__front = 0
    self.__size = 0
```

The function with problems:

```
def abandon_queue(self, index):
    if self.is_empty():
        raise ValueError('A fila está vazia! Não pode remover nenhum cliente')
    while int(index) > 8 or int(index) < 0:
        raise ValueError("Está fora da capacidade da fila")
    while 0 <= int(index) <= 8:
        remove = self.__data[int(index)]
        self.__data[int(index)] = None
        self.__front = (self.__front + 1) % len(self.__data)
        self.__size -= 1
        return remove
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `self.__data[int(index)] = None`, which sets the item at that location to `None`, use `self.__data.del(int(index))`, which removes the item and automatically decreases the list length

Comment: Side suggestion: save `int(index)` into a variable, so you don't have to keep getting it